# Log JSON message in Camel Route

Tags: java, apache-camel

I tried googling this and found nothing.

I know that you can use expression language like ${file:name} to log the file name, but how do you log the contents. How do you log the contents of the json message being passed forward?

Comment: Try googling harder as there is plenty of links to how to log something with Camel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can log the body and headers of the exchange by writing

```
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "test", "${body} and ${headers}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you log, but you can use a `TraceFormatter` with `showBody` set to true, read http://camel.apache.org/tracer.html